# Return A SQLDataReader Using SubSonic?

Tags: subsonic, sqldatareader

I am updating a web application and have decided to use SubSonic as it seems awesome and I want to learn it :)  I'm trying to return a `SQLDataReader` from a method I already have and have done it like this

```
public SqlDataReader GetAllCarTypes_dr()
{
    return (SqlDataReader)new Query("tblCarType").ExecuteReader();
}
```

Just checking this is the correct way to do it? Or is there a better subsonic syntax like `ExecuteSQLDataReader()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have specified is one way you can do it. However, there is no `ExecuteSQLDataReader()` function because it is redundant.

Since `SQLDataReader` already implements the `IDataReader` interface, there's no point in creating a function specific to a `SQLDataReader`.

You may consider returning the interface in the same manner SubSonic does, for example:

```
public IDataReader GetAllCarTypes_dr()
{
    return new Query("tblCarType").ExecuteReader();
}
```

and performing the assignment in your logic:

```
SQLDataReader reader = GetAllCarTypes_dr();
```

I would consider this the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it compiles, right? Just Kidding.

This link gives a little more of an explanation about when to use which:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/a8ed157d-e93c-4a8d-83a4-78645614b4ac

Just make sure you are closing the reader (readers?) somewhere so they don't leave open connections hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateDynamicControls()
{


    panGvHolder.Controls.Clear();

    Query qry = Northwind.Product.CreateQuery();
    qry.Columns.AddRange(Northwind.Product.Schema.Columns);
    qry.WHERE("UnitPrice > 15").AND("UnitsInStock < 20 ");
    //WHERE("UnitPrice > 15").AND("UnitsInStock < 30 ");



    using (IDataReader rdr = qry.ExecuteReader())
    {
        Response.Write("<table>");
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Response.Write("<tr>");
            for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Response.Write("<td>");
                Response.Write(rdr[i].ToString() + " ");
                Response.Write("<td>");
            } //eof for 
            Response.Write("</br>");
            Response.Write("</tr>");
        }
        Response.Write("<table>");
    }
} //eof method
```